# At what level is the oauth scope defined, at application or user level?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

In our project, we are using oauth (implementation - apifest) for token generation and validation. I am unable to understand the scope concept.
As per my understanding, oauth scope is used for authorization, which consists of some permission.

We have capability and role concept in our project, where:

Capability - permissions

Role - group of capabilities.

A role will be assigned to a user, based on which he functionality across application will be defined.

Role creation is dynamic.

Is this role concept the same in oauth? or is the scope defined at application level, where the users in that application will have the same scope?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to think of Scopes as a permission (or entitlement) to perform some action.

A role is typically a collection of permissions required to perform a "Job" or work within a "Project"

OAuth has no concept of a "Role"

[Scopes](https://oauth.net/2/scope/) are Requested by the client but are only Granted by the Authorization Server.

Scopes requested may not be granted and additional scopes may be granted that were not requested.

Comment: Is scopes defined for application?

Comment: They can be and that is not unusual. Often you will see scopes as URN: app1.example.com:read or app1.example.com:rw (https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/security/oauth/working-scopes  See: Best Practice)

Answer (score 0):

Scopes are used to delimit which applications can act on the behalf of the resource owner.

If you have an application, say a voting service, at voting.example.com. You have two roles: voters, which can see a poll, and vote, and admins, which can see the full results. The voting application enforces permissions based on these roles. A local user is assigned a local role. The application is protected using OAuth, so a user can be identified by a token.

You also have a social network app, social.example.com. This app provides a page where users can vote on the voting service. It is also connected to the same OAuth authorization server.

Finally, someone else has a reporting app, reports.example.com. This app would like to allow users to see the vote tally by requesting it from the voting service. It is connected to the same authorization server.

The authorization server, say iam.example.com. The authorization server has three clients, one for each app described above. There are two scopes defined in the authorization server, `voting`, and `reporting`.

The reporting app, when you login will request the `reporting` scope. The actual login happens on iam.example.com which will grant the token to reports.example.com. The login form will ask you, the user, whether you grant the client (reports.example.com) the right to act on your behalf and obtain reports from the voting service (provided by the `reports` scope). The scope will be recorded and associated with the token it sends to reports.example.com.

Now the reporting app can make a request to voting.example.com which says, "I would like to see the voting tally" The voting.example.com app will check the token, and provided it has the `reports` scope, it will send back the tally.

If it tries to make a request to the voting service to vote, it should be refused by voting.example.com, because the bearer token does not have the scope allowing you to vote. This must be enforced by the voting app. The authorization server manages which client is granted which scope.  Only to see the reports. This is not related to your role in the voting application itself.

OAuth itself doesn't provide a mechanism for identity validation, so you do not have a mechanism for validating who you are from the token, and what roles you have. [OpendID connect](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Overview) (OIDC) provides extra functionality for this by providing a scoped based identity endpoint protected by the authorization endpoint which allows it to reveal your identity to the app. So if we assume you have OIDC too, then it will check, from the token, who you are. It can then check it's database to see whether you have the right role, and whether you are allowed to see the tally before sending it.

What the scope enforces, is that the reports app, using it's client, can obtain a token to act on your behalf and ask for the information. When you grant the client the scope, you are allowing it to communicate with the voting service to obtain the information.

Roles are managed by your application and with a permission system, determine who can vote, who can read the votes.

Using something like OIDC, you can extend OAuth so the token identifies who you are. voting.example.com can then check that you are a) authorized to vote (by the local logic), b) that the application doing it on your behalf is allowed to act on your behalf (through the scope attached to the token).